# Как устранить ошибку Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function?

Tags: javascript

Нашел скрипт для якорей, пробую ставить себе и начал ругаться консоль
https://codepen.io/gduque/pen/BaKqdaN

Сам скрипт на который ругается

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
> at

```
$('.js-anchor-link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
  if(target.length){
    var scrollTo = target.offset().top;
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: scrollTo+'px'}, 800);
  }
});
```

Как решить этот конфликт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно подключить себе библиотеку *jQuery*

Конкретно в codepen указана 2.1.3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всего-навсего не та версия, спасибо!))